# Is possible to specialize a generic function in Dart?

Tags: dart, generics, optimization, instantiation

I have the following code:

```
T? ioData<T>(String label, T? value) {
  T? result;

  if (T is bool)
    result = ioBool(label, value as bool?) as T;
  else if (T is int)
    result = ioInt(label, value as int?) as T;
  ...
  else {
    throw Exception('Unsupported type: $T');
  }

  return result;
}
```

The compiler complains when I try this (C++ like) :

```
T? ioData<T>(String label, T? value) => throw Exception('Unsupported type: $T');

bool? ioData<bool>(String label, bool? value) => ioBool(label, value as bool?) as T;
int? ioData<int>(String label, int? value) => ioInt(label, value as int?) as T;

...
```

The error is of course:

```
The name 'ioData' is already defined.
Try renaming one of the declarations.dartduplicate_definition
test.dart(100, 6): The first definition of this name.
bool? ioData<bool>(String label, bool value)
```

Is there any way to do this so that the burden is on compile time rather than run time?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with C++ but I would think your proposed code would still make it run time and not compile time, especially if the function is called with a dynamic `value`. I think your original code is really the way to go. If you want it compile time efficient simply call `ioBool` directly for bools and `ioInt` for ints

Comment: Dart does not have function overloading. If you don't have any common class you use as restriction for `T`, you need to basically have your method be ready for handling any type, check what the type is at runtime, and then define the behavior that should happen.

Comment: @Ivo No this may be resolved at compile time, as the compiler already knows the type, he may directly select the right specialized function.  And of course, your suggestion to come back to the "carved flint era" ;-) is an option, but it is less flexible. For example, if a variable's type changes, more code needs to be updated with your option.

Comment: @julemand101 That's what I think, but I anyway asked this question because there is maybe some workaround (although I'm very skeptical).

Comment: Without function overloading, the best you can do is a switch() on the input value, match the incoming class, and select an appropriate branch that is typed properly.

Comment: @Randal Schwartz  Are you really sure that `switch` works on types? I don't think so.

Comment: It most certainly can match types: `result = switch (someValue) { Dog d => do dog thing, Cat c => do cat thing, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Dart has neither overloading (multiple functions with the same name in the same scope, distinguished by, e.g., parameter types), nor compile-time specialization of type parameters.

You should use the other-named functions, `ioBool` and `ioInt`, directly instead, if you know the type statically.

Also, your existing code doesn't actually work.
The

```dart
  if (T is bool)
```

test is always false, because `T` is a type variable, and it's being used as an *expression*, where it evaluates to a value of type `Type` (which is not a `bool`).

What I'd do instead is:

```dart
T? ioData<T>(String label, T? value) {
  if (value is bool) {
    return ioBool(label, value) as T?;
  }
  if (value is int) {
    return ioInt(label, value) as T?;
  }
  // ...
  if (value == null) {
    // do something for `null`
  }
  throw ArgumentError.value(value, "value", "Must be a bool, int, ...");
}
```

Don't focus on the type variable, focus on the *value*.
That is, unless you *want* to treat `null` differently depending on the type argument. In that case you may actually need to check what `T` is, which you cannot do directly using `is`.

In that case, you could possibly do:

```dart
class _Helper<T> {
  final T? value;
  _Helper(this.value);
}

T? ioData<T extends Object>(String label, T? value) =>
  switch (_Helper<T>(value)) {
    _Helper<int>(:var value) => ioInt(label, value),
    _Helper<bool>(:var value) => ioBool(label, value),
    // ...
    _ => throw ArgumentError.value(value, "value", "Must be a bool, int, ...")
  };
```

By reifying the type variable in an object, you can now do type checks against that object (because type checks can only be on objects, there is no way to directly compare types).
Notice that these are subtype checks, so if you also has a `num` case, it should come after `int` and `double`.

The one alternative, which requires restructuring, would be to use extensions:

```dart
extension IoDataInt on int? {
  int? ioData(String label) => ioInt(label, this);
}
extension IoDataBool on bool? {
  bool? ioData(String label) => ioBool(label, this);

}
```

Then you can do:

```dart
int? i = ...;
i = i.ioData("label");
```

and it will only work for types which actually has that extension.
The problem with extensions is that they must be imported directly into every library which uses them, but that's no different from accessing a top-level function like `ioData`.

Comment: Very nice structure, which proves that it is often interesting to ask questions for which you think there is no answer. You'll often learn something new out of it. Thanks! Now, I never saw the notation ":var" and I nor google nor the AI's I use helped me with explanations. Could you please explain it, or refer to a documentation about it if it is too long or complex to explain?

Comment: The `_Helper<int>(:var value): ...` is a switch expresssion *pattern*, introduced with pattern matching in Dart 3.0. https://dart.dev/language/patterns